# Unable to resize the graph inside Bootstrap Panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using jqplot jquery plugin to render the graph and Bootstrap for my design. The Panel (with title PERFORMANCE) is a bootstrap panel. It's body contains the graph rendered via jqplot.

[image: jqplot jQuery plugin used inside Bootstrap Panel] 
The problem I am facing is when I resize the browser window, the graph doesn't resizes, instead it overflows out from the Bootstrap Panel.
Any ideas what measures should I be taking?

Thanks for reading.